# C# Custom Attributes not being applied

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, metadatatype

I'm trying to apply attributes to fields using the MetadataType attribute class. I haven't been able to apply a custom attribute to a field in a partial class. Some of the examples I have been following are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx>) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ff664465(v=pandp.50).aspx).

My end game is to try and flag all the fields in a class that I am required to "do some work with".

In the example below, I want the field "Name" to have the FooAttribute applied. In real life, I'm dealing with generated code....

In my very contrived example, I have a partial class - Cow, which is generated code;

```
namespace Models
{
    public partial class Cow
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Colour;
    }
}
```

I need the Name field to use my FooAttribute, so I have done this;

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Models
{
    public class FooAttribute : Attribute { }

    public class CowMetaData
    {
        [Foo]
        public string Name;
    }

    [MetadataType(typeof(CowMetaData))]
    public partial class Cow
    {
        [Foo]
        public int Weight;

        public string NoAttributeHere;
    }

}
```

This works great for the Weight field, which has the FooAttribute applied  - but I would expect that because it is in the partial class. The Name field does not pick up the attribute from the metadata, and this is what I really need.

What am I missing, or have I got it all wrong?

**Update:** This is how I am searching for fields with the FooAttribute ;

```
public static void ShowAllFieldsWithFooAttribute(Cow cow)
{
    var myFields = cow.GetType().GetFields().ToList();
    foreach (var f in myFields)
    {
        if (Attribute.IsDefined(f, typeof(FooAttribute)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", f.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

The result of this is:
Weight

But I am Expecting:
Name
Weight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes are part of metadata and they are not affects the compiled results. Setting `MetadataType` attribute to the class doesn't spread all metadata to the properties/fields of the class. So you have to read the `MetadataType` attribute in code and use metadata from type defined in `MetadataType` attribute instead of initial class (or together as it is in your case)

Check the sample:

```
    var fooFields = new Dictionary<FieldInfo, FooAttribute>();

    var cowType = typeof (Cow);
    var metadataType = cowType.GetCustomAttribute<MetadataTypeAttribute>();
    var metaFields = metadataType?.MetadataClassType.GetFields() ?? new FieldInfo[0];

    foreach (var fieldInfo in cowType.GetFields())
    {
        var metaField = metaFields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == fieldInfo.Name);
        var foo = metaField?.GetCustomAttribute<FooAttribute>() 
                           ?? fieldInfo.GetCustomAttribute<FooAttribute>();
        if (foo != null)
        {
            fooFields[fieldInfo] = foo;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I understand that. I'll update my question to show how I am looking for the attribute.

Comment: It is almost the same I've provided just change `fooFields[fieldInfo] = foo;` to `Console.WriteLine( fieldInfo.Name);` and you'll get what you need

Comment: That's the problem though, the custom attribute isn't applied to the name field. By the way, I'm unable to compile your example because of the MetadataClassType in this line:    var metaFields = metadataType?.MetadataClassType.GetFields() ?? new FieldInfo[0];

Comment: If the attribute is only for you than just read it from metadata as I proposed. In case it is something else going to read it than, it seems that it wouldn't work. BTW, what is the error? check the type of `metadataType` in your case, I'm using  .Net 4.5.2

Comment: My apologies re the error: I cut and paste again and your sample works fine. Although I still don't understand why my example doesn't work, you have certainly solved my problem, thank you.

Comment: In the sample I've provided, code is checking attributes from the specified in `MetadataTypeAttribute` class and in the class itself, in your sample, code checking only the main class and not considering data from metadata class

Comment: A few years later, but... using .NET Core, I found that I had to use GetProperties() - GetFields() returned an empty array